# URLs unchanged after migration

Tags: url-rewriting, migration

I have my company's blog at http://blog.analytixsolutions.com and now I've moved it to http://blog.aixsol.com but I have the URLs still pointing to the former address.

I used the commonly recommended search and replace plugin to change the URLs in the backend.

I also fired the following queries in phpmyadmin without any success.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'OLDURL', 'NEWURL') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'OLDURL','NEWURL');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'OLDURL', 'NEWURL');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'OLDURL','NEWURL');
```

What am I doing wrong here? This is the tried and tested technique I've used to migrate a lot many other sites prior to this.

Comment: Could it be that `WP_SITEURL` or `WP_HOME` is set in your `wp-config.php` file? If they aren't, could you use PHPMyAdmin to check whether the options with `option_name` `siteurl` and `home` are both set to the new URL?

Comment: Thanks but I've already set them to the appropriate new url.

Comment: All right, and what about my first question? Could it be that `WP_SITEURL` or `WP_HOME` (constants) is set in your wp-config.php file?

Comment: No, there isn't any mention of them in wp-config

Comment: Could you try running `site_url( '/' );` and posting here what it displays?

Comment: Do I need to make a new file like we do for phpinfo()?

Comment: No, you don't, you can place it in your theme's functions.php on the `init` action.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to functions.php. I didn't have to do the above as the previous developer used the following to specify URLs

`update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');`

Comment: All right, do you want help or not? If you do, stop fooling around and start answering questions.

Comment: @engelen [Be nice](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Sometimes it's a little hard to narrow question down for all parties involved, no reason to make it harder with throwing edgy remarks around. :)

Comment: You did provide me with enough help engelen and thank you for that. I don't see why do we have to get hostile.

As I said the previous developer used the above mentioned functions in functions.php which overrode the particular settings in the back-end. I removed it and now everything's fine. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Misunderstanding there, I figured you meant you didn't have to do `site_url` check because your developer used `update_option( 'siteurl' [..] )` already. My bad, sorry about that! I'm glad your problem was solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous developer had hard coded

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com'); 
update_option('home','http://example.com');
```

in functions.php which on being removed resolved the issue. Thanks everyone for churning in your suggestions.